# How to execute SQL in the IntelliJ Ultimate SQL Console?

Tags: sql, database, intellij-idea, console, datagrip

In IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2, the `SQL Console` opened from the `Database` panel lets me enter some SQL.

Unfortunately, when I click the green triangle icon in its upper-left corner, sometimes my SQL executes and sometimes it does not. Sometimes I need to select all the text before hitting the triangle to make it execute, sometimes I do not. Apparently there is some logic or magic trick intended by this tool that escapes me.

➠ How to execute the SQL Console?

[image: screen shot of the SQL Console in IntelliJ 2017.2]

The [documentation for *Database Console*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-console.html) says:

> Use this icon or shortcut to execute the selected (highlighted) SQL statement or statements.
>
> If nothing is selected, the current statement is executed.

That is not the behavior I see when running on macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Comment: Are you sure the caret (cursor) is on the statement you are trying to execute? If the statement is multiline like on your screenshot and the caret is on line 2 or 3, nothing will be executed. Please check if the statement is executed if you place the caret on line 1.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, the behavior you describe is what I experience. So where the doc says “statement” they *really* mean “line”? That seems more of a bug than a feature – I see no advantage. Anyways… Is there any way to just make the whole dang script run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control what IDE executes on this action in the `Preferences`/`Settings` > `Tools` > `Database` > `Execute in Console`.

[image: Execute in console]

You may want to set some of those to the **Whole script**.